# Placeholder - Component ReactJS

Tags: component

estimados como puedo colocar un placeholder en un componente, el componente es una librería de terceros dinámico y no puedo editar el input, alguna forma de pesar el placeholder de manera directa.

Gracias.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Comp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  render() {
    return (

              <div>
              <Checkout type="card" placeholder={'texto'} />
              </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Comp;
```

Comment: Hola @Sixto. Puedes importar la librería o comentarnos cuál es para que podamos ayudarte? de este modo, no podemos verificar tu problema directamente, y la respuesta se vuelve muy compleja, ya que no conocemos tampoco la librería.

Comment: Probaste quitándole las llaves y dejar sólo el texto

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz, Hola gracias por responder, no me explique bien, no tanto pasa por la librería, mi pregunta es, cualquier componente que importe <Component /> hay forma de pasarle directamente un placeholder..?

Comment: Hola @Sixto Si revisas la definición de W3C del placeholder https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp, verás que únicamente se puede asociara a los input. 
 Si el objeto "Component" hereda de input, y está correctamente programado, entiendo que podrías conseguir que apareciera. En caso de que no sea un input, será complejo. Es posible que tengas que reprogramar la librería para hacerlo llegar

Comment: Googleando un poco estoy viendo esto - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-placeholder - Me da la sensación (no conozco react.js) que será algo parecido a una directiva de angular, o similar, https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/client-frameworks/react/react-placeholders pero la verdad no sé cómo puedes inyectar el atributo placeholder al select que tuvieras debajo, si es el caso

Comment: Ok, me quedo claro alguna idea en poder un texto indicativo dentro del componente, que actué o simule un placeholder, lo necesito dentro del campo no como label, si no como si fuera un placeholder. que podría probar, Gracias